# Ruby on Rails: Developing in the cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud

I've taken over a rails site, and learning along the way.

It's been a real pain getting the site pulled down from git and working properly in OSX (mysql, REE, ruby_inline gem etc). It seems can be a little fiddly to get some of this stuff working cross os.

Our live production runs on ubuntu.

I have been developing on a cloud hosted server using vi / git etc and it's working quiet well, but it's a little slower (not much) to refresh pages etc and test.

I'm curious, is anyone developing in the cloud? Or do you run a local linux VM. Curious to hear about thoughts and experiences from the battlefield.

Many thanks,

b

Comment: Most of the hosting service providers run Linux (especially virtual hosts).  However, I don't find much of a difference between running rails on OSX vs Linux (they both coming from the same parent).  What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: One example REE, there is a post on passengers blog on how to get this working, but I had the issue before hand so trying to use rvm to install ree I couldn't get it working.. Problems with some gems that use native libraries as well e.g mysql, ruby_inline etc.

Comment: This probably should be on webmasters.se, as this doesn't really relate to programming.

Comment: I develop on OSX and deploy on Ubuntu and I have yet to find any real differences between the two. Sure, some gems require different methods to install, but in general no problems. I would imagine that the problems you are running into stem from not separating the two environments properly. For example, do you really need to run your development with passenger? Mongrel is usually a better choice for development.

Comment: I was told I was required to run passenger / ree to get working locally by an experienced dev on the site. Would there be any reason this is true? Weird dependencies or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "default" environment when you have OS X on local and Linux on production servers. Many of rails-developers use it for everyday development and testing process.

You told "It's been a real pain getting the site pulled down from git and working properly in OSX", just ask a question here what exactly had a pain to setup? Ruby? Rails? Git?

No, it's almost the same platform, OS X is a BSD-based system.

- **Homebrew** will help you to setup DB engine, GIT
- **RBEnv** - multiple Ruby version handle
- **Rubygems** - crossplatform GEM packaging

"I have been developing on a cloud hosted server using vi" - what does it mean? It's actually not a pattern of development process. What if you broke something straight on production server while business users are doing a demonstration to clients?

"I'm curious, is anyone developing in the cloud" - rather no, than yes. You can develop anywhere, but the code snapshot should be available to test and preproduction usage.

If we are talking about standard approach and typical task, it already has typical patterns and solution to achieve the goals

Comment: It's a separate VM for development, I don't develop on production.

Comment: ok, Thoughtbot provides a good post howto setup OS X workplace http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/8700977975/2011-rubyists-guide-to-a-mac-os-x-development

Comment: just in case, look at the recent Railscasts #292 Virtual Machines with Vagrant (http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find most people develop on osx, some on linux, but by far the normal way to do it is locally rather then on a remote server

Comment: Do you suppose it's most on OSX and some on linux?  Or vice versa?  I wonder if there have been any surveys on that lately.

Comment: From the hundreds of developers I know about Boston MA & MIT it's about 80-90 % Mac's.  I own and have developed on a 3 machine types (Win/Mac/Linux) and personally prefer Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: I've always been on linux myself; used to feel a little funny at ruby/rails conferences with my thinkpad in a sea of macbooks.  I wonder if the ratio has evened out a bit these days though.

Comment: i said that based on personal experience and what i see at tech meetups/conferences. that being said, where im working right now we are using linux. The up side is probably package management, the downside is everything is just nicer on osx (fonts, windows, small gui apps, etc)